# Adding prizes to OpenAI Gym maze environment

Tags: python, openai-gym

Is there a way to modify the OpenAI Gym environment slightly by adding a fixed number of prizes (e.g. 2) in random places on the map? Such that the agent will not only find the exit, but will also pick up the prizes on the way.

I have the following code for a Q learning algorithm using `maze-v0`

```
import gym
import gym_maze 
import numpy as np

env = gym.make("maze-v0")

states_dic = {} #dictionary to keep the states/coordinates of the Q table
count = 0
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        states_dic[i, j] = count
        count+=1
        
n_actions = env.action_space.n

#Initialize the Q-table to 0
Q_table = np.zeros((len(states_dic),n_actions))


#number of episode we will run
n_episodes = 10000
#maximum of iteration per episode
max_iter_episode = 100
#initialize the exploration probability to 1
exploration_proba = 1
#exploartion decreasing decay for exponential decreasing
exploration_decreasing_decay = 0.001
# minimum of exploration prob
min_exploration_proba = 0.01
#discounted factor
gamma = 0.99
#learning rate
lr = 0.1

rewards_per_episode = list()


#we iterate over episodes
for e in range(n_episodes):
    #we initialize the first state of the episode
    current_state = env.reset()
    done = False
    
    #sum the rewards that the agent gets from the environment
    total_episode_reward = 0

    for i in range(max_iter_episode): 
        env.render()  # For image you MUST call this
        current_coordinate_x = int(current_state[0])
        current_coordinate_y = int(current_state[1])
        current_Q_table_coordinates = states_dic[current_coordinate_x, current_coordinate_y]

        if np.random.uniform(0,1) < exploration_proba:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
        else:
            action = int(np.argmax(Q_table[current_Q_table_coordinates]))


        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

        next_coordinate_x = int(next_state[0]) #get coordinates to be used in dictionary
        next_coordinate_y = int(next_state[1]) #get coordinates to be used in dictionary


        # update our Q-table using the Q-learning iteration
        next_Q_table_coordinates = states_dic[next_coordinate_x, next_coordinate_y]
        
        Q_table[current_Q_table_coordinates, action] = (1-lr) *Q_table[current_Q_table_coordinates, action] +lr*(reward + gamma*max(Q_table[next_Q_table_coordinates,:]))
    
        total_episode_reward = total_episode_reward + reward
        # If the episode is finished, we leave the for loop
        if done:
            break
        current_state = next_state
    #We update the exploration proba using exponential decay formula 
    exploration_proba = max(min_exploration_proba,\
                            np.exp(-exploration_decreasing_decay*e))
    rewards_per_episode.append(total_episode_reward)
```